# opening pdf at the cursor on lyx

Tags: lyx, pdf, forward-inverse-search, preview

While creating a preview on lyx , I expect the pdf to show me the position of the text at which cursor is positioned. The default behaviour seem to open pdf at first page. How can I change this behaviour?

Comment: I guess you're using Adobe Reader? What you want can be accomplished with LyX + [SumatraPDF](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/free-pdf-reader.html) (but not with Adobe, I think). See http://wiki.lyx.org/Windows/LyXWinTips#toc6 for how to set it up; and http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/SyncTeX#toc6 for implementing backward/forward search functionality.